# NGINX SSI Not working

Tags: nginx, web-server, server-side-includes

I'm having trouble getting SSI to work on NGINX.  You can see the problem if you hit http://www.bakerycamp.com/test.shtml.  Here is the contents of that file:

```
<!--# echo hi -->
```

If you hit this in a browser, you see the SSI directive in the content - so apparently NGINX is not interpreting the SSI directive.

My NGINX config file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name     bakerycamp.com www.bakerycamp.com;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/bakerycamp.access.log;
    index           index.html;
    root            /home/bakerycamp.com;
    location /      { ssi   on; }

    # Deny access to all hidden files and folders
    location ~ /\.  { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
}
```

I did not build NGINX from sources but installed it using apt-get.  I assume it has the SSI module (since that is default) but perhaps not?  Should I just bite the bullet and rebuild from sources?  Is there anyway to tell if the installed NGINX supports SSI and my config is just wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In nginx, the SSI directive `echo` is used to echo the contents of variables, not arbitrary text.

To test SSI, try something like:

```
<!--# set var="test" value="Hello nginx!" -->
<!--# echo var="test" -->
```

See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#commands) for further details.